# Error 500 - Internal Server Error con script de php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente sitio en el cual tengo un formulario que manda las variables por `post` a un `script` en `php` donde tengo la función `mail` que manda estas variables por `mail`:
Este es el formulario:

```html
<form action="formulario.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Apellido" name="apellido">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Número Móvil" name="telefono">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="mail" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ganarplata">QUIERO GANAR MÁS PLATA<br> VENDIENDO CLEAN WAY</button>
</form>
```

Y este es el script php:

```php
<?php
header('index.html');
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

// the message
$msg = "<html>
<head>
<title>Formulario Clean Way</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><b>Nombre:</b>
<br>
". $nombre ." 
</p>
<p><b>Apellido:</b>
<br>
". $apellido ." 
</p>
<p><b>Teléfono:</b>
<br>
". $telefono ." 
</p>
<p><b>Email:</b>
<br>
". $email ." 
</p>


</body>
</html>"
;
// More headers
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html' . "\r\n";;



// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// send email
mail("felipepinoredes@gmail.com","Formulario Contacto",$msg, $headers);
}
?>
```

Al presionar el botón de `submit`, recibo un

> Error 500 - Internal Server Error

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Encontré un error, tal como me lo señalaron más abajo:

Al principio, la función header debía ir así:

header('Location: index.html');

Ahora mi problema es que sigue sin poder mandar el mail. ¿Qué más me falta?

Comment: Has podido mirar el log, para ver donde te marca el error?

Comment: Si la web está en construcción y no en producción, puedes activar los errores en tiempo de ejecución para que te de más pistas de lo que puede estar ocurriendo. Puedes activar los errores incluyendo `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` en las primeras lineas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La siguiente línea:

```
header('index.html');
```

genera un error, ya que no es un [encabezado HTML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Cabeceras) válido.

Al no tener ninguna función evidente en el código, deberías eliminarla.

Para mayor información, lee en el manual de PHP: **[header()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)**.

Comment: Justamente, eso estaba muy mal.

Tenía que ser así:

header('Location: index.html');

Así no me sale el error 500, pero ahora tengo otro problema y es que no manda el mail.